# Splitting a sentence and retrieving a specific word

Tags: c++, string, vector

I've managed to write the following piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;    
int main()
{
    string sentence;
    getline(cin, sentence);
    char* ptr = &sentence[0];
    while ( *ptr != '\0' ){
        if ( *ptr == ' ' ){
            cout << endl;
        }
        else{
            cout << *ptr;
        }
        ptr++;
    }
}
```

By using that I can print each word of a sentence separately. However I want to store them and then retrieve them. Here's a sample run:

```
Enter the sentence:This is a sample sentence.
Which word do you want to see ?:4
sample
```

I don't know how to proceed from my code above. I thought storing each letter in a char array, then convert these arrays to strings and store them in a `vector<string>` but couldn't figure it out.

I would like to do it with only using given libraries and without using any splitting functions if possible.

**EDIT:This is what i've tried lately.Doesn't work though.**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char letter;
    vector<string> words;
    vector<char> temp;
    vector<char> sentence;
    while( cin >> letter ){   // ctrl-z to break
        sentence.push_back(letter);
    }
    char* ptr = &sentence[0];
    while ( *ptr != '\0'){
        while ( *ptr != ' ' ){
            temp.push_back(*ptr);
            ptr++;
        }
        words.push_back(str(temp));
    }
```

}

**EDIT2: Here's a solution with sstream**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout << "Sentence: " << endl;
    string sentence;
    getline(cin, sentence);
    istringstream sin(sentence);
    vector<string> tokens;
    string word;
    while (!sin.eof()){
        sin >> word;
        tokens.push_back(word);
    }
    cout << "Which word ?: " << endl;
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    cout << tokens[n - 1] << endl;
}
```

**EDIT3: Rite, got it.Here's the solution i wanted.**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int wordbyword(string sentence, char** words)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
    while (sentence[i] != '\0'){
        if (sentence[i] != ' '){
            words[j][k] = sentence[i];
            k++;
        }
        else {
            j++;
            k = 0;
        }
        i++; 

    }
    return j;   
}

    int main()
    {
        string sentence;
        cout << "Sentence: "<< endl;
        getline(cin, sentence);
        int size = sentence.length();
        char** words = new char*[size];
        for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            words[i] = new char[size];

        int wordCount = wordbyword(sentence, words) + 1;    
        while(1){
            cout << "Word number: " << endl;
            int n;
            cin >> n;
            if ( n == 0){
                cout << "Terminating..." << endl;
                break;
            }
            else if ( n > wordCount || n < 0)
                cout << "Word doesn't exist" << endl;
            else
                cout << words[n - 1] << endl;
            }

    }
```

Comment: You could count the number of whitespaces you've seen so far. The 4th word is after the 3rd whitespace.
(Things can get a bit more complicated depending on your definition of word)

Comment: You could use a `std::istringstream`, then read into a `std::string` with `>>`. This will split on whitespace.

Comment: `std::stringstream` is pretty much made for this. (`#include <sstream>`).

Comment: Splitting depends only on whitespaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to copy that in a vector:

```
istringstream iss(sentence);
vector<string> tokens;
copy(istream_iterator<string>(iss),
     istream_iterator<string>(),
     back_inserter<vector<string> >(tokens));
```

Comment: `back_inserter` is not used enough!

Comment: Although good advice for non-beginners, I don't think there is enough explanation for OP. Sure he can mindlessly copy and use it, but it really doesn't help him in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually very straight-forward. You need to set up a loop that will run while input is being taken. For each iteration you should then `push_back` to the vector the new string:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> words;
    std::string word;

    while (std::cin >> word)
    {
        words.push_back(word);
    }

    int idx = 0;

    std::cout << "Which word do you want to see? ";
    std::cin  >> idx;

    std::cout << words[idx];
}
```

Comment: Yeah but the whole point is to enter the sentence as a whole and then splitting up that sentence.